# Propagate (Node.js) Events through Clases

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, events

Let's say I have a class A that extends EventEmitters, so it can emit an event. Now let's say I have another class B that extends class A. (How) can I set it up so that an event emitted by class A gets propagated through class B?

```
class A extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  e() {
    this.emit('classA');
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

let mI = new A();
let mB = new B();
mB.on('classA', p => console.log('classA')); // event should arrive in class B instance???
mI.e();
```

Comment: If your question is about subclassing between `A` and `B`: that doesn't make sense, that's not how inheritance works. If your question is about forwarding events from one instance  `mI` to another instance `mB`, the inheritance doesn't matter, they problem is the same as if they're both instances of `A`.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by 'that's not how inheritance works'? A Class can certainly extend another class that extended another class, right?

Comment: Yes, but inheritance is relevant only for a *single* instance. So you do `const x = new B(); x.on(…); x.e()`. The object is an instance of B and at the same time an instance of A, that's why you can use the `e` method on it (and at the same time it's an instance of `EventEmitter`, that's why you can use the `on` method on it). But you don't need to do any "setup" for this to work, inheritance means that the code works for any object that is an instance of `A` (i.e. if the code began with `const x = new A()`) or any subclass of `A` (such as `B`).